# MAC_install4j6: Unable to detect Java

Tags: java, osx-elcapitan, install4j

MAC OS X - Yosemite and El Capitan

I have made an installer using install4j 6.1.2(32 bit) and installed on MAC machine but it doesn't detect Java.

> **Java 6 and 1.8** is already present but still getting message,

I have tried with different combination

> Java min = 1.6 & min = 1.7 same message "Need at least 1.7..." &
>   for min = 1.8 & max = 1.8 : "You need at least java 1.8 ..."
>   [image]

So is it searching for 32 bit java? or there is some other issue? How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug the JRE search sequence by launching the installer from the command line like this:

```
INSTALL4J_LOG=yes installer.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
```

For Java 7+, you have to make sure to select "Installed Oracle JRE" on the "JRE" step of the media wizard.

Also, on the "General Settings->Java Version" step, the "JRE search sequence" has to contain the "Search Window registry and standard locations" entry.